# Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/kerberos' on ubuntu in a nodejs project

Tags: node.js, kerberos

```
Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/kerberos'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Repo/firm-datahub-api/node_modules/authenticate-uxtf/node_modules/kerberos/lib/kerberos.js:1:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Module._compile (/mnt/c/Repo/firm-datahub-api/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/mnt/c/Repo/firm-datahub-api/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Repo/firm-datahub-api/node_modules/authenticate-uxtf/node_modules/kerberos/index.js:2:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Module._compile (/mnt/c/Repo/firm-datahub-api/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/mnt/c/Repo/firm-datahub-api/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

I tried every available solution but getting same result.
I installed, kerberos server, client, workstation, what am I missing?

Comment: It sounds like part of the Node.js dependencies weren't installed properly. Try running `npm install` inside the project directory _and watch for errors_.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for your response. I removed and installed all the packages again, even node and npm. But getting same error.

Comment: What happens if you run `npm install kerberos`? Does it complete succesfully?

Comment: Yes, i tried `sudo npm install -g kerberos --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

Comment: Please do what I suggested: `npm install kerberos`. Not as root, and not with the other arguments.

Comment: I tried ` npm install kerberos` so many times and it didnt work, but after i removed all the packages and did it again as you said,**it worked**. Thanks Again @robertklep.